# How do Lexical Environment Works Exactly?

Tags: javascript

Hey so i dont know why but lately i've been quite obsessive with lexical environment
that's a subject i already learned 1 year and a half ago but lately i feel like i dont trust myself if i know this 100% right so please tell me if i'm correct or incorrect.

take a look at the following code

```
var name = 'John',lastName = 'Douglas'
function printName(){
   {
    let lastName = 'Jordan';
    var name = 'Michael'
   }
   console.log(name,lastName);
}

printName();
```

so based on my knowledge the result that's going to be printed is "Michael Douglas" now i will explain in detail why step by step

1. so global execution context is created and a lexical environment for that global execution context is also created

`var name = 'John'` will get attached to the lexical Environment of the global execution context
Why ? because at the moment  the current lexical environment is the global lexical environment therefore it will get attached to it.
`lastName = Douglas` will also get attached to the global lexical environment
and also the `printName` will also get attached to the global lexical environment because the current lexical environment is the global.

2.after that i'm calling `printName()` so now Javascript is looking for `printName` so it's checks if the current lexical environment has `printName` and it does have it,so it's working and we are calling the function

3.a new execution context is created along with a new lexical environment now the current lexical environment is changed to `printName` lexical environment.

4.Before execution occur a stage called Creation Phase aka Hoisting will happend basically Javascript will try to find the variables declaration and functions statements inside `printName` and it will put it inside the `printName` lexical environment.
now during that process JS encounter a `{` basically a Block but still it doesn't prevent JS from allocating those variables inside the current lexical environment(printName LE)

Javascript wont add `let lastName = 'Jordan'` to the current lexical environment(printName LE)
because `let lastName` is a block scoped, basically Javascript sees that we enter to the block during the creation phase so it wont add `let lastName` to the current lexical environment.
therefore we wont be able to access it.
but `var name ='Michael'` will get attached to the current lexical environment(printName LE) even though it's declared inside a block Why ? because the variable was declared with the `var` keyword
and variables with the `var` keyword are function scoped meaning it will be possible to access them anywhere inside the function and in order for them to be accessible anywhere inside the function they have to get attached to the function lexical environment.

5. Ok the creation phase was ended now we execute the code.
   while Javascript executing it's encountering `{` so it knows that now we are inside a block
   so now a new lexical environment is created and now the current lexical environment is the block's lexical environment and again creation phase(aka hoisting) is occuring setting all the variables of type `let` and `const` to undefined inside that Block

6.now execution phase so it's sees `let lastName = 'Jordan'` so it's search where lastName is in memory and it's found that it's inside the current lexical environment which is the Block
now it sees `name = 'Michael'` it's search where name was created so it's search
it's sees it's not part of the Block lexical environment so it goes to the outer reference of the Block lexical environment and its found the variable inside `printName` lexical environment
and it assign the value `Michael` to it.

7. now finally we finished executing the code inside the Block and now we are exiting the Block and now the current lexical environment is back to `printName` lexical environment
   now we got to the line where `console.log(name,lastName)` and now it's finding where `console.log`  via scope chain and it found it in the Global Lexical Environment.
   now it's searching for `name` so it's found it inside the current lexical environment
   and now it's searching for `lastName` it didn't found it inside the current lexical environment so it goes to the outer reference and found it inside the parent lexical environment which is the global lexical environment

because of that we got the result "Michael Douglas"

Comment: That is a long story, but I don't find what your question is. You seem to be answering your own "Why" questions.

Comment: oh i'm just not too sure if i'm exactly right..